# when I import apk file from eclipse I found unkowen character

Tags: eclipse, import, character, apk, intel-xdk

the file became apk from intel xdk and I try to import it from eclipse but eclipse give me unknown characters , so what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Install a tool like [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) and use the following command to unzip the apk file 
apktool d C:\filename.apk C:\folder_of_the_decompiled_files. 
Use the files created within this new folder to import the project onto eclipse. It is not possible to directly import an apk file.

Comment: okay , check the file (http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/1BDDNVFP/k.rar_links) , an issue when I export by eclipse , and also I can't find android tools in eclipse ?